# Spring Batch: Proper way of persisting the processing status of each individual item

Tags: spring-batch

Scenario:

- I'm using Spring Batch `2.2.1.RELEASE`.
- I have an `Account` repository, containing users and their e-mail addresses.
- Weekly, I want to send out e-mails to all users. This is the periodic "batch".
- **I have the requirement to persist information about the current processing state of each individual e-mail (... *e-mail*, ...*account*, ...or equivalently, *batch item*)**.

**Processing states** for each individual e-mail include

- `EMAIL_PROCESSING_FOR_THIS_ACCOUNT_HAS_STARTED`
- `EMAIL_PROCESSING_FOR_THIS_ACCOUNT_HAS_ERROR`
- `EMAIL_PROCESSING_FOR_THIS_ACCOUNT_SKIPPED_BECAUSE_OF_OPTOUT`
- `EMAIL_PROCESSING_FOR_THIS_ACCOUNT_SUCCESSFUL`.

If I have this requirement implemented, I can query the relevant repository to get information such as: "*For calendar week 2013-W40, user John Doe's e-mail status is SUCCESSFUL.*"

Currently, my Spring JavaConfig `@Configuration` looks like this:

```
@Bean
public Job emailSpringBatchJob() {
    return springBatchJobBuilderFactory.
            get("job").
            start( emailSpringBatchStep() ).
            build();
}

@Bean
public Step emailSpringBatchStep() {
    return springBatchStepBuilderFactory.
            get("step").
            <Account, MimeMessage> chunk(1).
            reader( accountReader() ).
            processor( accountToMimeMessageProcessor() ).
            writer( mimeMessageWriter() ).
            build();
}

@Bean
public ItemReader<Account> accountReader() {
    IteratorItemReader<Account> itemReader = new IteratorItemReader<>( accountRepository.getAllAccounts() );
    return itemReader;
}

@Bean
public ItemProcessor<Account, MimeMessage> accountToMimeMessageProcessor() {
    SomeMailProcessor itemProcessor = new SomeMailProcessor();
            // plus some configuration for itemProcessor
    return itemProcessor;
}

@Bean
public ItemWriter<MimeMessage> mimeMessageWriter() {
    MimeMessageItemWriter itemWriter = new MimeMessageItemWriter();
    //plus some configuration for itemWriter
    return itemWriter;
}
```

**Now I'm stuck finding the "right way" to implement the requirement of persisting each e-mail's current processing status:**

- Should I use Spring Batch's `ItemStream` and tinker with its provided `ExecutionContext`?
- Should I use Spring Batch's `ItemReadListener`, `ItemProcessListener`, and `ItemWriteListener`?
- Should I use Spring Batch's `ExceptionHandler`?
- Should I extend/write my own `ItemReader`, `ItemProcessor`, and `ItemWriter` classes and put any 
  business logic related to this requirement there?
- ?

Which parts of Spring Batch can I leverage to elegantly fulfill my requirement?

Answer (score 2):

The typical way to handle requirements like this is via listeners.  This separates the concerns of the processing itself with the state management.  You may want to look at the ChunkListener beyond the various Item based listeners since the state for a group of items should move together.  The only time that is not the case would be the EMAIL_PROCESSING_FOR_THIS_ACCOUNT_SKIPPED_BECAUSE_OF_OPTOUT state which would require an ItemProcessListener.

Comment: During the `ItemWriter` "phase", does Spring Batch provide means to get a reference from each output item back to each related input item? ... For example, in `ItemWriter.write(List<MimeMessage> items)`, for each single `MimeMessage` item, depending on the delivery success or delivery failure of that mail item, I need the reference back to the `Account` in order to update the processing state. My work-around currently is to map from the `MimeMessage`'s e-mail address back to `Account`, but this seems unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: It does not.  That is by design.  While the writing of an email is probably a bit more of a specialized case than most other writers in that the writer takes the built output and just persists it instead of taking a POJO and doing the mapping somehow, the goal is to keep each phase as decoupled as possible.